# Why are some values 0 when using performance.getEntries

Tags: javascript, performance

I am using `performance.getEntries()` to measure and log how long some of my assets are taking to download in real life for my users.

I want to work out the time spent actually downloading a specific asset, and to do this I am doing the following (this is a simplified version of my code):

```
var entries = performance.getEntries();
entries[0].responseEnd - entries[0].responseStart
```

However for many of my assets responseStart is set as 0, making the responseEnd time useless. I thought this might be because my assets are over HTTPS but I have some external resources loaded over HTTPS which return timing data.

Has anyone come across this?

Thanks very much

Comment: Why don't you use the [`duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceEntry/duration) property of the [PerformanceEntry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceEntry)?

Comment: I am using this and in itself it is a very useful measurement. But I also want to know how long is actually spent downloading an asset, and not the DNS lookup, handshake, waiting on the server or anything else like that.

Comment: Check [W3: Resource Timing Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/). There you can find the conditions when `responseStart` has to be zero

Comment: In my experience, most likely reason for `responseStart` to be 0 is a cross-origin request and that origin doesn't set [Timing-Allow-Origin](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/#http-timing-allow-origin) header.